# CSS3 Slideshow Bugs

Tags: jquery, html, browser, css, slideshow

I've tried to implement this CSS3 slideshow on my site (http://www.designmadeingermany.de/slideshow/)

But I can't seem to disable the horizontal scrolling. On the demo site, it's impossible to scroll horizontally and when the mouse rollsover the right and left edges of the page, an arrow pops up which changes the slide onclick.

On my site, horizontal scrolling is enabled. How do I disable it and have the arrow-on-mouseover-navigation thing to work? (my url: http://cakelovecouture.businesscatalyst.com/index.html)

Thanks for the help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use overflow: hidden on #u336.

You're also missing the CSS to properly position #a2 and #a3 (back and next buttons)

```
.nextbutton {
cursor: url('right.png'), e-resize;
right: 0;
}
.nextbutton, .backbutton {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
}
```